# Old school electronic technician, new to DACs

Tags: dac

*Old school (1993) electronic 2-year graduate familiar with the now-obsolete simple ML2035 8 bit DAC. Haven't dabbled in electronics in nearly 27 years.*

There are no replacements for the ML2035. I'm located in an area with frequent power losses during seasonal changes. I'm designing a 60 Hz sine wave generator to inject 60 Hz into a 120 V H-bridge to run some back up lighting and possibly some minor appliances.

The ML2035 is a rugged 8-pin DIP DAC that can produce a very accurate and steady 60 Hz sine wave using a 74HC4060 with a 4.194304 MHz crystal as a clock going to a 74HC165 with very few discrete components. Simple and rugged design.

My question is with the new DACs out there today requiring a microcontroller and some coding, are there any DACs that I can utilize the 74HC4060 and 74HC165 as a microcontroller workaround?

I am not that versed in coding and don't want to learn coding just for this application. Looking to be able to simply replace an IC without any coding if an IC failure occurs.

Comment: It's not a DAC, it's a DDS chip, and it needs a serial 16 bit programming word. You could replace it with any number of analog solutions, or an MCU if you want a single chip. What distortion are you aiming for?

Comment: you can buy them on eBay, if you're happy with the markup, and a chance of a dud

Comment: you can also buy very low cost DDS modules, though their programming will be different.

Comment: The cheapy ‘pure sine wave’ inverters will most likely be cheaper and better than home-brewing an analog solution. All your solar inverters and wall battery units use digital techniques for the inverter for cost and efficiency.

Comment: Note that incandescent lighting can run just fine on DC. Fluorescent lighting can't - I think. CFL and LED bulbs may or may not work - you'd have to take one apart and see what kind of circuit that type of bulb uses.

Comment: I’m interested to know how you’ll get a sine wave from that ripple counter.

Comment: The ripple counter is not making the sinewave. The ripple counter is feeding a clock to the parallel to serial 74hc165 IC. The 74hc165 feeds the serial to the ML2035 DAC

Answer (score 0):

How about an old-school solution with no digital ripple counters, and no shift registers?  Just a simple clock followed by a low-pass filter using off-the-shelf parts.  No micro-controller, and no software required.

Put a 60Hz square-wave (from any source you like) and feed that into a suitable filter.  However, to get a sine-wave with low distortion, say, 1% (ie: 40dB down at the third harmonic, 180Hz) you may need a high-order filter which may be impractical to implement.  You can use any of the common filter design tools (say, from TI or Analog Devices) to work up a design, below is an image of one I did based on passing 60Hz and having 40dB attenuation at 180H.  It looks OK, until you notice at all the tricky R & C values you may need, eg: 2.67k, 2.49k, 1.18k, 2.32k, 3.16uF, etc.

[image]

An alternative solution: put 6kHz (60Hz x 100) into an off-the-shelf high-order ratio-metric filter, such as the MAX7400, available from all the common vendors (Digikey, Mouser, etc).

From the datasheet:
"The MAX7400/MAX7403/MAX7404/MAX7407 family of 8th-order, lowpass filters provides sharp rolloff with good stopband rejection. All parts operate with a 100:1 clock-to-corner frequency ratio and a 10kHz maximum corner frequency. These devices accept a
single +5V (MAX7400/MAX7403) or +3V (MAX7404/ MAX7407) supply".

With this device, you will easily achieve a sine-wave with less than 1% THD.  This seems like the perfect fit for your application.

Image below is from the datasheet, showing the pin-pout and its equivalent circuit.

[image]

Comment: Sinewave drift is something I'm concerned about. The crystal helps in the stability and the ML2035 has a look up register for the waveform.

Comment: For both options I offered, you can use any square-wave generator (clock) you like - discrete stable (using R-Cs & transistors), or 555 timer, or a crystal-based solution, or PLL, whatever.  The drift you get will be set by the clock, not the filter.  If you're concerned about duty-cycle not being perfectly 50%, then put the clock into a divide by 2.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a DAC, the easiest (and cheapest) solution is to use an MCU (most of which come with built-in oscillators and crappy DACs these days) and a sine wave lookup table. Alternatively, you can use sine PWM and add a low pass filter to remove the need for a DAC. Even an ancient AVR MCU like the ATMEGA328P (old school Arduino) running at 8MHz (built-in oscillator) is more than capable of producing 60Hz sine.

Comment: Thought about the 328 and the arduino, but that requires coding.

Comment: Writing 5 or 6 lines of code will end up with better results and less headache than using logic ICs to do the same thing in hardware. If you really like hardware solutions, get a cheap FPGA or CPLD and make your own NCO (numerically controlled oscillator)

Comment: The 74hc4060 is roughly 50 cents. And the 74hc165 is roughly 1.70. Really cannot be cheaper or simpler.

Comment: @Hippy How much do you think a low end MCU or CPLD/FPGA is? You can MCUs for under a buck that run at 100MHz these days.

Comment: @Hippy both the AT TINY and PIC family are fairly well documented and beginner friendly: https://www.mouser.co.uk/c/semiconductors/embedded-processors-controllers/microcontrollers-mcu/8-bit-microcontrollers-mcu/?m=Microchip~~NXP%7C~STMicroelectronics&number%20of%20i%2Fos=8%20I%2FO~~88%20I%2FO&instock=y&sort=pricing&rp=semiconductors%2Fembedded-processors-controllers%2Fmicrocontrollers-mcu%2F8-bit-microcontrollers-mcu%7C~Number%20of%20I%2FOs%7C~Manufacturer